# Making a navigation using arrays

Tags: php

I know this is going to be voted as a bad question but I always have trouble with these.
I am making a php navigation using arrays and my code keeps falling short, mainly in foreach statements. Hopefully if you look you can see where I am trying to go

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>navigation</title>
        <?php
            $pages = array("index.html" => "Home");
        ?>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <?php
                foreach($pages as $link => $page){
                    echo '<li> <a href=" $link "> $page </a> </li>';
                }
            ?>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're trying to reference variables within single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

`$link` and `$page` aren't going to get parsed here, since they're within single quotes:

```
echo '<li> <a href=" $link "> $page </a> </li>';
```

Do this instead:

```
echo '<li> <a href="' .$link . '"> ' . $page . '</a> </li>';
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: or `echo "<li> <a href='$link'> $page </a> </li>";`

Comment: Yep, that works too. I prefer "my" way just so I can always have double-quotes in my HTML.

Comment: Thank you, I always forget that part

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
echo '<li> <a href=" $link "> $page </a> </li>';
```

To this:

```
echo "<li> <a href=\"$link\"> $page </a> </li>";
```

And you should be good to go.

Check up on strings, particular interpolation
http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php